# Is this variant of bitwise cyclic tag Turing-complete?

Tags: computability-theory, computer-science, discrete-dynamical-systems

*[Cross-posted](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/48349/is-this-variant-of-bitwise-cyclic-tag-turing-complete) from Theoretical Computer Science.*

---

[CT](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bitwise_Cyclic_Tag#The_language_CT) is an extremely minimalist programming language that [can simulate](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bitwise_Cyclic_Tag#Computations_in_BCT) arbitrary [tag systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_system), and is therefore Turing-complete. A program consists simply of a string of 3 commands that operate on a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) of bits:

| Command | Description |
| --- | --- |
| A | pop |
| B | push 0 if front is 1 |
| C | push 1 if front is 1 |

These commands are executed in cyclic order from left to right. The queue is initialized with a single 1. If the queue becomes empty, the program terminates.

Let CT2 be the language that replaces command B with "push 0" (unconditionally). **Is CT2 Turing-complete?** One way to prove this would be to find a way to simulate CT or arbitrary tag systems in it, perhaps through some clever encoding.

Here are the [busy beaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) sequences for both languages with a 10K-step runtime limit (runtimes exceeding this are considered non-terminating):

| Program length | CT | CT2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 9 | 3 |
| 4 | 16 | 8 |
| 5 | 25 | 19 |
| 6 | 36 | 17 |
| 7 | 49 | 49 |
| 8 | 399 | 899 |
| 9 | 2159 | 1367 |
| 10 | 1407 | 300 |
| 11 | 7490 | 9893 |
| 12 | 9130 | 3348 |

Notice that CT2 also exhibits a rapid growth that is suggestive of Turing-completeness.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was asked and answered at CS Theory.